# DB2 for z/OS SQL: OVERRIDING USER VALUE not permitted

Tags: sql, db2, zos, mvs

I have two tables with identical definition but different owners.
Created a new table based on one of these:

```
CREATE TABLE SHADOW.ADM LIKE USR1.ADM;
ALTER TABLE SHADOW.ADM ADD SHTYPE CHAR(1);
ALTER TABLE SHADOW.ADM ADD SHCOUNTER INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SHADOW.IXADM ON SHADOW.ADM(SHCOUNTER) USING STOGROUP SG1;
```

When I try to execute the SQL below I get syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO SHADOW.ADM
  OVERRIDING USER VALUE
  SELECT A.*,0 FROM     
    (SELECT O.*,'B' FROM USR1.ADM O UNION ALL
     SELECT N.*,'A' FROM USR2.ADM N) A;
```

The error is:

```
  OVERRIDING USER VALUE CLAUSE IS NOT PERMITTED. SQLCODE=-109, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.72.44
```

The strange thing is, the SQL below executes without error:

```
INSERT INTO SHADOW.ADM
  OVERRIDING USER VALUE
  SELECT A.*,'B',0 FROM USR1.ADM A;
```

Is this a bug in DB2's SQL parser or am I missing something?

btw: This is on DB2 for z/OS V7, accessed from DBeaver as client.

Comment: Support for DB2 v7 for z/OS ended on 30-Jun-2008, over ten years ago, are you certain that's the version you're using?

Comment: Some problem with your example, the number of columns returned by the fullselect does'nt seem to match the SHADOW.ADM number of columns?

Comment: @cschneid Yes, I'm 100% sure. We were hired to migrate the data to a modern platform. Better late than never.

Comment: @mao Nice catch, one of the ALTER TABLE statements was missing. But it makes no difference whatsoever. It turned out that using UNION instead of UNION ALL works fine ... until you hit a long text column.